# ParameterMissingエラーを解決したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, reactjs, typescript

#### 解決したいこと

railsのパラメータのエラーを直したいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

```rb
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: learning_material
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.3.1/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:495:in `require'
```

#### 環境と流れ

・Dockerを使い、バックエンド側（Rails）とフロントエンド側(TypeScript React)に分けて開発をしています。OSはWindowsですが、WSL2のLinux（Ubuntu20.04）を使用しています。
・React側のフォームで入力データを受け取り、それをRails側に保存する。

#### backend側（＊長いため関係がありそうなコードのみ）

#### /backend/app/controllers/api/v1/learning_materials_controller.rb

```rb
class Api::V1::LearningMaterialsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    binding.pry
    learning_material = user.learning_materials.create!(learning_material_params)
    
    if learning_material.save
      render json: learning_material
    else
      render json: learning_material.errors, status: 422
    end
  end


  private
    def learning_material_params
      params.require(:learning_material).permit(:subject, :body, :file, :answer)
    end
end
```

#### user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
            # Include default devise modules.
            devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
                    :recoverable, :rememberable, 
                    # :trackable, 
                    :validatable,
                    # :confirmable,
                    :omniauthable
            include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
    has_many :learning_materials, dependent: :destroy
end
```

#### learning_material.rb

```
class LearningMaterial < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
    default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
    validates :subject,presence:true
    validates :body,   presence:true
    has_one_attached :file
    validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

#### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', skip: [:omniauth_callbacks], at: 'auth', controllers: {
        registrations: 'api/v1/auth/registrations'
      }

      namespace :auth do
        resources :sessions, only: %i[index]
      end
      resources :users do
        resources :learning_materials
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### front側

#### App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react"
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, useParams, Link, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

import CommonLayout from "./templates/CommonLayout"
import { getCurrentUser } from "apis/auth"
import { User } from "interfaces/index"
import  LearningMaterialList  from "./components/organisms/LearningMaterialList";

// グローバルで扱う変数・関数
export const AuthContext = createContext({} as {
  loading: boolean
  setLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
  isSignedIn: boolean
  setIsSignedIn: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
  currentUser: User | undefined
  setCurrentUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User | undefined>>
})


const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { userId } = useParams();


  return (

  <>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loading, setLoading, isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn, currentUser, setCurrentUser}}>
        <CommonLayout>
          <Routes>

            <Route path="users/:usersId" element={<LearningMaterialList />} />
            <Route path="users/:usersId" element={<Users />} />
            <Route
                      path="/"
                      element={
                      <PrivateRoute>
                        <Home />
                      </PrivateRoute>
                      }
                    />
          </Routes>
        </CommonLayout>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### LearningMaterialList.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Grid } from "@material-ui/core"
// import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from '@mui/styles';

import LearningMaterialForm from "./LearningMaterialForm"
import LearningMaterialItem from "./LearningMaterialItem"

import { getLearningMaterials } from "../../apis/learning_material"
import { LearningMaterial } from "../../interfaces/index"

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  container: {
    marginTop: "3rem"
  }
}))

const PostList: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [learning_materials, setLearningMaterials] = useState<LearningMaterial[]>([])
  const { usersId } = useParams();
  const handleGetLMs = async () => {
    
    const { data }  = await getLearningMaterials(usersId)
    setLearningMaterials(data.learning_materials)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleGetLMs()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
      <Grid container direction="row" justifyContent="center">
        <Grid item>
          <LearningMaterialForm
            handleGetPosts={handleGetLMs}
          />
          { learning_materials?.map((learning_material: LearningMaterial) => {
            return (
              <LearningMaterialItem
                key={learning_material.id}
                learning_material={learning_material}
                handleGetLMs={handleGetLMs}
              />
            )}
          )}
          <h1>LearningMaterial</h1>
        </Grid>   
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default PostList
```

#### LearningMaterialForm.tsx

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { experimentalStyled as styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import { Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField"
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box"
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton"
import PhotoCameraIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PhotoCamera"
import CancelIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Cancel"

import { makeStyles, createStyles } from '@mui/styles';

import { createLearningMaterials } from "../../apis/learning_material"
// frontend/app/src/apis/learning_material.ts
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  form: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    width: 320
  },
  inputFileBtn: {
    marginTop: "10px"
  },
  submitBtn: {
    marginTop: "10px",
    marginLeft: "auto"
  },
  box: {
    margin: "2rem 0 4rem",
    width: 320
  },
  preview: {
    width: "100%"
  }
}))

const Input = styled("input")({
  display: "none"
})

const borderStyles = {
  bgcolor: "background.paper",
  border: 1,
}

interface PostFormProps {
  handleGetPosts: Function
}

const PostForm = ({ handleGetPosts }: PostFormProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const { usersId } = useParams();

  const [subject, setSubject] = useState<string>("")
  const [body, setBody] = useState<string>("")
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState<string>("")
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File>()
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState<string>("")

  const uploadImage = useCallback((e: any) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    setFile(file)
  }, [])

  // プレビュー機能
  const previewImage = useCallback((e: any) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    setPreview(window.URL.createObjectURL(file))
  }, [])

  // FormData形式でデータを作成
  const createFormData = (): FormData => {
    const formData = new FormData()

    formData.append("subject", subject)
    formData.append("body", body)
    if (file) formData.append("file", file)
    formData.append("answer", answer)
    

    return formData
  }

  const handleCreatePost  = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const data = createFormData()

    await createLearningMaterials(usersId,data)
    .then(() => {
      setSubject("")
      setBody("")
      setAnswer("")
      setPreview("")
      setFile(undefined)
      handleGetPosts()
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleCreatePost}>
        <TextField
          placeholder="Hello World"
          variant="outlined"
          multiline
          fullWidth
          rows="4"
          value={subject}
          onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            setSubject(e.target.value)
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          placeholder="Hello World"
          variant="outlined"
          multiline
          fullWidth
          rows="4"
          value={body}
          onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            setBody(e.target.value)
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          placeholder="Hello World"
          variant="outlined"
          multiline
          fullWidth
          rows="4"
          value={answer}
          onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            setAnswer(e.target.value)
          }}
        />
        <div className={classes.inputFileBtn}>
          <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
            <Input
              // accept="image/*"
              id="icon-button-file" 
              type="file"
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                uploadImage(e)
                previewImage(e)
              }}
            />
            <IconButton color="inherit" component="span">
              <PhotoCameraIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </label>
        </div>
        
        <div className={classes.submitBtn}>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            variant="contained"
            size="large"
            color="inherit"
            disabled={!subject || subject.length > 140 || !body || body.length > 140}
            className={classes.submitBtn}
          >
            Post
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
      { preview ?
        <Box
          sx={{ ...borderStyles, borderRadius: 1, borderColor: "grey.400" }}
          className={classes.box}
        >
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            onClick={() => setPreview("")}
          >
            <CancelIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <img
            src={preview}
            alt="preview img"
            className={classes.preview}
          />
        </Box> : null
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default PostForm
```

#### apis/learning_material.ts

```
import { AxiosPromise } from "axios"
import client_lm from "./client_lm"
import { LearningMaterialApiJson } from "../interfaces/index"

// 取得
export const getLearningMaterials = (usersId: string|undefined): AxiosPromise<LearningMaterialApiJson> => {
  return client_lm.get(`${usersId}/learning_materials`)
}

// 作成
export const createLearningMaterials = (usersId: string|undefined, data: FormData): AxiosPromise => {
  return client_lm.post(`${usersId}/learning_materials`, data)
}

// 削除
export const deleteLearningMaterials = (usersId: string|undefined, id: string): AxiosPromise => {
  return client_lm.delete(`${usersId}/learning_materials/${id}`)
}
```

#### 自分で試したこと

binding.pryを利用して以下のことを確認しました。
・userはきちんと値が取れている
・learning_material_paramsは以下のエラーを吐く

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: learning_material
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.3.1/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:495:in `require'
```

・learning_materialはnil
・この場面（binding.pryを利用している場面）でparamsを調べると

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"subject"=>"f", "body"=>"f", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fe40d5f9a30 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20220802-1-ixp5lc.mp3>, 
@original_filename="Night_Sea.mp3", @content_type="audio/mpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Night_Sea.mp3\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n">, 
"answer"=>"f", "controller"=>"api/v1/learning_materials", "action"=>"create", "user_id"=>"3"} permitted: false>
```

なぜかこのように正常にパラメータを取れている。
・エラーになっているファイルを開くと

```
[7] pry(#<Api::V1::LearningMaterialsController>)> /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.3.1/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb
(eval):2: unknown regexp options - lcal
api_1    | /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.3...
api_1    |     ^~~~~~
api_1    | (eval):2: unexpected fraction part after numeric literal
pi_1    | .../bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.3.1/lib/action_controller/metal/...
api_1    | ...                           ^~~~
```

このようになっているが、なぜこのようなエラーが起きるのか分からない。

・以上のことから、ストロングパラメータを利用している部分に何かしら問題があると予想しました。しかし、コントローラーファイルのどこが間違っているのか分かりません。
公開しているファイルに不備があれば追加で投稿します。何かしらアドバイスがあればよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

解決致しました。どうやらストロングパラメータの記述方法が間違っていたようです。正しくは以下の通りです。

```
private
    def learning_material_params
      # params.require(:learning_material).permit(:subject, :body, :file, :answer) ###ダメな例
      params.permit(:subject, :body, :file, :answer) ###正しい例
    end
```